# Exposing geometry nodes attributes

Tags: scripting, drivers, geometry-nodes

Is it possible to output an attribute as a float/int/bool input value to another node?
In my particular example I have a switch node and want the "is_exploding" attribute to drive the switch input. What is the best way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this:

[image]

So the is_exploding drives the result and determines whether attribute A or attribute B is take to result.

Comment: Well, i've been doing this with the math node up until now, so thanks, I'll use mix from now on. but it's not what I need. I need to output attribute values to other nodes (non-attribute nodes)

Comment: can u please explain why you need that? normally you can do everything with attributes...

Comment: I explained it in the question. I need the switch to be driven by an attribute. It switches between instances with particle nodes and without any, in my case